# Approval Process Pardot

Tags: marketing-cloud, approval-process, pardot

I am working with a client in the process of migrating from Marketing Cloud to Pardot.

As a part of its Email Governance, the client uses approvals in marketing cloud to ensure all outbound communication has been approved by a manager.

We find Pardot lacking in this regard and need advice with regards to best practice in Pardot around approvals? Is there any way to hack this? what is everyone else doing?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't any approval process in Pardot as you said. You might add your client's email address to a list and send test proofs to them.

Comment: The only way to fully enforce this approval process is by building your own custom 3rd party app that utilizes Pardots API connections to do all your sending. Which is a fairly large and expensive project.